# How to access elements defined in another xml?

Tags: android

I need to set a listener to a button defined in another xml. How do I do that? I tried this but it gives me RunTimeException.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.leavestatus_info_activity);
cancel_leave_button = (Button)findViewById(R.layout.leave_status_reason).findViewById(R.id.cancel_leave);
```

Here is my logcat:

```
03-12 11:36:19.125: E/AndroidRuntime(689): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 11:36:19.125: E/AndroidRuntime(689): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.empover.hrms.activity/com.empover.hrms.activity.LeaveStatusInfoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-12 11:36:19.125: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-12 11:36:19.125: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-12 11:36:19.125: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-12 11:36:19.125: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-12 11:36:19.125: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-12 11:36:19.125: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-12 11:36:19.125: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-12 11:36:19.125: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 11:36:19.125: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-12 11:36:19.125: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-12 11:36:19.125: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-12 11:36:19.125: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 11:36:19.125: E/AndroidRuntime(689): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-12 11:36:19.125: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at com.empover.hrms.activity.LeaveStatusInfoActivity.onCreate(LeaveStatusInfoActivity.java:61)
03-12 11:36:19.125: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-12 11:36:19.125: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-12 11:36:19.125: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Where is your LogCat

Comment: what´s You intention for getting a button in another xml? Maybe there is another way to get what You want...

Comment: I feel you need to inflate other xml in this activity to get access to the button of other xml.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs this button is an element of the chidview in ExpandableListView. I need to perform some action when this button is pressed after the listview is expanded.

Comment: @VeronikaGilbert can you post your xml and some more code please.

Answer (score 4):

See if this works:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.first_layout);
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.second_layout, null);

    Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.my_button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```

What I'm doing here is inflating the second layout before setting an onclick listener to it. In your code, by doing `findViewById(R.layout.leave_status_reason).findViewById(R.id.cancel_leave);`, what's going on is that you're looking in your original layout for a layout called leave_status_reason, which doesn't exist.

**Edit** 
Okay, it's probably way late and you've probably moved on by now, but I want to correct this for posterity: to get this to work, you need to replace `null` with the your parent layout container and use the View inflater instead. So the line would be:

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.first_layout);

View view = View.inflate(this, R.layout.my_layout, container);
```

and then it should work.

Comment: Your solution seems to have worked. I t doesn't give any error but it does not execute the listener too.. :(

Comment: cancel_leave_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
  {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Cancel button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
  });

Comment: Right--in all honesty, I wasn't sure that it would actually execute the listener. A better method would be to set a callback from Activity2 to Activity1 that tells Activity1 to execute the listener (or whatever) when Activity2 is activated.

Answer (score 1):

First inflate other layout by `LayoutInflater.inflate()` and then find the view in `InflatedLayout`

```
cancel_leave_button = (Button)InflatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.cancel_leave);
```

Comment: if You trying to do that in another activity, a nullpointer exception will be thrown, like happened in OP´s case. The Button is in another xml and is not related to the layout which is set in the activity...